# Why doesn't this python list assign it's value in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

When the loop through ports runs, the variable afc_rem only gets set to all_fields on the first loop, then when values are removed, it never regains the full list of all_fields. Why does this happen?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    all_fields = ["byr","iyr","eyr","hgt","hcl","ecl","pid","cid"]
    
    ports = ["byr", "iyr"]
   
    for port in ports:
        afc_rem = all_fields
        for field in afc_rem:
            if field in port:
                afc_rem.remove(field)
```

Comment: Here the working code. You should try.

    if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    all_fields = ["byr","iyr","eyr","hgt","hcl","ecl","pid","cid"]
    
    ports = ["byr","iyr"]
    
    out = list()
    for i in all_fields:
        if i not in ports:
            out.append(i)
    
    print(out)

It iterates all_fields one by one. if ports is not found in all_fields, it appends to the new list.

Answer (score -1):

## Explanation

Basically, when you assign `afc_rem = all_fields` then `afc_rem` is just a reference to in memory which means thats `afc_rem` still points to `all_fields`.
You can observe this by doing inside loop:

```
print(id (afc_rem))
print( id ( all_fields))
```

Thus while removing items from `afc_rem` also removes items from `all_fields`.

## Solution:

Try deep copy:

```
import copy
afc_rem = copy.deepcopy(all_fields)
```

Comment: The `list` contents are all immutable types; a deep copy isn't necessary. Shallow copying with `afc_rem = all_fields[:]` or `afc_rem = all_fields.copy()` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes. But if `afc_rem` becomes nested then shallow copy would not work. Would it??? Since the deep copy caters both the situation and there isn't a memory contrains it's better to use deep copy.